# Leaflet - Popup description anchor on top of Marker

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

I am using [Leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) and ingest a [Geojson](http://geojson.org/) file in order to create Popups and associate them with (geojson) Features.

For the icons i use this [library](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers) (~>Leaflet.ExtraMarkers).

Below you can see the code for creating Markers and Popups.

**Creating a Marker**

```
    iconMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
      icon: 'fa-globe',
      markerColor: 'blue-dark',
      shape: 'square',
      prefix: 'fa'
    });
```

**Creating a Popup**

```
popup = L.popup({'closeButton': false}, layer)
                .setLatLng(LatLonCoords)
                .setContent("Content");
```

**Geojson sample**

```
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "id":1,
            "zoom":8,
            "alt":"..",
            "image":"..",
            "popup":".."
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               16.940584,
               41.100433
            ]
         }
      },
    ...
      ]
   }
```

The picture shows a Marker with an open Popup (default style of Leaflet).

[image]

### Question:

How could i change the anchor of the Popup description and how could i modify the "Arrow" (preferably without changing the default css)?

*

> Note: I am aware of options that i can put in Popup (aka. offset) or in  Extramarkers (aka. popupAnchor) but the problem is that the description and therefore the height of the Popup is variable.

*

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "changing" the arrow and anchor? Do you want it to be on another side (left/right), different style, hide it?

Comment: I want to find a way to change them. It may be left, right, top, down or even hide the anchor programmatically.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no way to do that currently, with just standard Leaflet. Some people asked on SO in the past, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144334/open-leaflet-popup-at-bottom-of-marker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144334/open-leaflet-popup-at-bottom-of-marker). There are some suggestions for the "Rrose" plugin, which changes the anchor automatically if too close to the map border, I don't know if it works with current Leaflet builds.